# filter data from array of objects based on selected value

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I have a component which is showing data from an array:

my first component:

```
firstArr = [
  {
    "code": "firstArr item 1",
    "name": "firstArr item 1"
  },
  {
    "code": "firstArr item 2",
    "name": "firstArr item 2"
  },
  {
    "code": "firstArr item 3",
    "name": "firstArr item 3"
  },
]

<FirstComponent
  data={firstArr}
  onUpdate={selectedValue => {
    setval(selectedValue);
    console.log(selectedValue);
  }}
/>
```

Now I have another list:

```
list2 = {
  "firstArr item 1": [
      {
          "code": "firstArr Subitem 1",
          "name": "firstArr Subitem 1"
      }
  ],
  "firstArr item 2": [
      {
          "code": "firstArr Subitem 2",
          "name": "firstArr Subitem 2"
      }
  ],
  "firstArr item 3": [
      {
          "code": "firstArr Subitem 3",
          "name": "firstArr Subitem 3"
      }
  ],
}
```

Now based on `selectedValue` from `firstArr`, I need to filter `list2` and show only sub items of `selectedValue`

I tried:

```
var dataNew = list2.filter(function (i) {
  return i = "firstArr item 1"
})
```

But this is giving error

Comment: This not gonna work since you have grouped item you can access it via: list2[selectedItem.code]

Comment: That second list would probably easier to manage if you changed it from an object to an array of objects where each object has a new key called "parent". You could just then do `find(obj => obj.parent === value);` and then extract the other props that you need from the returned object.

Comment: @Andy These lists and array are coming from API's, so I cannot change it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for this:

```
var firstArr = [
  {
    code: "firstArr item 1",
    name: "firstArr item 1"
  },
  {
    code: "firstArr item 2",
    name: "firstArr item 2"
  },
  {
    code: "firstArr item 3",
    name: "firstArr item 3"
  }
];

var list2 = {
  "firstArr item 1": [
    {
      code: "firstArr Subitem 1",
      name: "firstArr Subitem 1"
    }
  ],
  "firstArr item 2": [
    {
      code: "firstArr Subitem 2",
      name: "firstArr Subitem 2"
    }
  ],
  "firstArr item 3": [
    {
      code: "firstArr Subitem 3",
      name: "firstArr Subitem 3"
    }
  ]
};

var dataNew = Object.keys(list2)
  .filter((x) => x === "firstArr item 1")
  .map((i) => {
    return list2.find((x) => x.code === i);
  });

console.log(dataNew);
```

Comment: @Poke  in console I am getting `[ { code: 'firstArr item 1', name: 'firstArr item 1' } ]` . I need data from list2

Comment: You get this because you have array in first Arr item you have to use newData[0]

Comment: @pratteekshaurya ok i changed the code so it returns the item from list2

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use [a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement) for this.

This example assumes that the array only contains one object, and you only need the properties from that array to populate the new select. If you need the whole array just remove the `[0]` from `list[key][0]`.

```js
const list={"firstArr item 1":[{code:"firstArr Subitem 1",name:"firstArr Subitem 1"}],"firstArr item 2":[{code:"firstArr Subitem 2",name:"firstArr Subitem 2"}],"firstArr item 3":[{code:"firstArr Subitem 3",name:"firstArr Subitem 3"}]};

const value = 'firstArr item 2';

let out;

for (const key in list) {
  if (key === value) out = list[key][0];
}

console.log(out);
```